# how users should work with ambari cluster

Tags: hadoop, ambari

My question is pretty trivial but didnt find anyone actually asking it.

We have a ambari cluster with spark storm hbase and hdfs(among other things).

I dont understand how a user that want to use that cluster use it.

for example, a user want to copy a file to hdfs, run a spark-shell or create new table in hbase shell.
should he get a local account on the server that run the cooresponded service? shouldn't he use a 3rd party machine(his own laptop for example)?
If so ,how one should use hadoop fs, there is no way to specify the server ip like spark-shell has.

what is the normal/right/expected way to run all these tasks from a user prespective.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected way to run the described tasks from the command line is as follows.

First, gain access to the command line of a server that has the required clients installed for the services you want to use, e.g. HDFS, Spark, HBase et cetera.

---

During the process of provisioning a cluster via Ambari, it is possible to define one or more servers where the clients will be installed.
[Here you can see an example of an Ambari provisioning process step. I decided to install the clients on all servers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEkRH.png)

Afterwards, one way to figure out which servers have the required clients installed is to check your hosts views in Ambari. [Here you can find an example of an Ambari hosts view: check the green rectangle to see the installed clients.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CkEA.png)

Once you have installed the clients on one or more servers, these servers will be able to utilize the services of your cluster via the command line.
Just to be clear, the utilization of a service by a client is location-independent from the server where the service is actually running.

---

Second, make sure that you are compliant with the security mechanisms of your cluster. In relation to HDFS, this could influence which users you are allowed to use and which directories you can access by using them. If you do not use security mechanisms like e.g. Kerberos, Ranger and so on, you should be able to directly run your stated tasks from the command line.

Third, execute your tasks via command line.

Here is a short example of how to access HDFS without considering security mechanisms:

```
ssh user@hostxyz # Connect to the server that has the required HDFS client installed
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp # Command to list the contents of the HDFS tmp directory
```

Comment: First, thanks for helping out.
If I understand you correctly, for every usage i might have to move from server to server. for example i have got spark on server 1 and storm on server 2, then i need to run spark-shell (for example) from server 1 and storm jar.... from server 2?
is there a way to dedicate one server from the cluster to hold all the binaries for all the services the cluster service?

Comment: @nadav I edited my initial answer. Hope this will help you with your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Ambari views](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.0.1/bk_ambari-views/index.html), especially on **Files** view that allows browsing HDFS